# How to submit form from bootstrap modal

Tags: php, sql

I need help submitting the PHP form.

I've got a table which shows some records from database using php while loop.

One of the field is called Image. I want to add form in that field so people can add image to that product.

The way I am thinking to do is have a button "Upload" in image fields. AND also have a bootstrap modal which is placed outside of table and would contain image upload form.

So when user click "Upload", the bootstrap model open with form and clicking on submit would save the image for that clicked product.

To start off with, This is my upload button in table.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value = "<?php echo $row['id_stk']?>" data-id= "image-upload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#image-upload">Upload</button>
```

Here is my bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg image-viewer-modal" id="image-upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h2>Image Upload</h2>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="post" id="UploadImage">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  type="file"  class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sucess"> Upload</button>

                                 <img id="target" src="#" alt="your image" />
                            </form>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer image-modal">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div


                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

ANd my Script

```
    $( "#UploadImage" ).submit(function( event ) {
          alert($(this).attr("value"));
          event.preventDefault();
    });
```

**My question is How I can pass the details of  clicked row into a form, 
Because SQL Insert statement would do something like "Update Products SET image WHERE id = ?**

ANd How I can submit this form.

Thank you.

**Re-edited**
This is table, which has upload button.

[image]

The code for upload button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value = "<?php echo $row['id_stk']?>" data-id= "image-upload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#image-upload">Upload</button>
```

So when I click that, model open (which is place outside of table and loop).
Here is modal code.

```
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg image-viewer-modal" id="image-upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <!-- FORM FOR IMAGE UPLOAD -->

                        <form method="post" id="UploadImage">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input  type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_stk']?>" >
                                <input  type="file"  class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sucess"> Upload</button>

                             <img id="target" src="#" alt="your image" />
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer image-modal">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is modal picture

[image]

Here is code for upload form button. I just want to alert. But it shows nothing.

```
  $( "#UploadImage" ).submit(function( event ) {
     var customerId = $(this).find('input[name="id"]').val();
    alert(customerId);
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place a hidden input field inside the form tag and set its value with the ID of the record to be updated. This way you can get the ID of the record in the method/action to which the form submits to.

```
<form method="post" id="UploadImage">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="id" id="idToSend">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input  type="file"  class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sucess"> Upload</button>

                             <img id="target" src="#" alt="your image" />
                        </form>
```

Attach the submission of the form with click of "Upload" button.

```
$('.uploadButton').click(function(){
    $('#idToSend').val($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: My form is in bootstrap modal which is placed outside the table and while loop. So how hidden field value can be set to variable. Because that PHP variable will only exist inside the loop

Comment: Please show the complete code snippet then. It's just a small issue.

Comment: I have re-edited my original question. I have added some code and browser snippets. Look for word "Re-edited " after that I added code snippets.

Comment: This didn't work. When I click uoloadButton, modal appears and disappear in next second. This is because we are submitting the form on upload button click event.

Comment: did you assign the "Upload" button class "uploadButton" ??

Comment: Yes I assigned the class "uploadButton" to upload button which appears inside table; which than user clicks and model appear containing form

Comment: I missed the '' in the Jquery snippet, can you please retry following the updated code.

Comment: Are you assigning the Jquery to submit button which is inside the model below form.??

Comment: So basically the idea is:

On click of the button, get the ID from the "value" attribute of the button and assign to the "value" attribute of the hidden input field of the form and submit the form on clicking the submit button of the form.

    $('.uploadButton').click(function(){
        $('#idToSend').val($(this).val());
    })

Updated the answer.